# listview and notifydatasetchanged in android

Tags: android

I have a `CustomListView` with `ImageView`.

When I select any item the image view changes. I need to display the selected items in another ListView. I went through documents and I got a clue to use `notifydatasetchanged()`..but problem is I dont know how to use it or where to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look on the sample Example to know how to use notifyDatasetChanged

### Example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyListView extends ListActivity {
    ArrayList<String> pens = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = null;
    private static final byte UPDATE_LIST = 100;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pens.add("MONT Blanc");
        pens.add("Gucci");
        pens.add("Parker");

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pens);
        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("..Item is clicked..");
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.what = UPDATE_LIST;
                updateListHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        });



        // System.out.println("....g1..."+PhoneNumberUtils.isGlobalPhoneNumber("+912012185234"));
        // System.out.println("....g2..."+PhoneNumberUtils.isGlobalPhoneNumber("120121852f4"));

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        System.out.println("...11configuration is changed...");
    }

    void addMoreDataToList() {
        pens.add("item1");
        pens.add("item2");
        pens.add("item3");

    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String pen = o.toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, id + "You have chosen the pen: " + " " + pen,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private Handler updateListHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case UPDATE_LIST:
                addMoreDataToList();
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;

            }
            ;
        };
    };




}
```

Answer (score 3):

actually `notifydatasetchanged` method we are using for `adapter` not for `listview`.

suppose you are using BaseAdapter for listview..
so use

```
adaptername.notifydatasetchanged() where your image is changing.
```

for more info then [click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Put your selected items into an array.
And use an adapter to put the items into the listview. How did u do it? And please don't mark your question as a code, it's hard to read now.

```
lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Osszekapcsolas.this,R.layout.list_black_text,R.id.list_content, yourArray);
lv1.setAdapter(adapter1);
adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

where list_black_text in az an xml containing a textview for each rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/list_content"
android:textColor="#222222"
android:layout_margin="4dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But i suppose you know this. However, in this code there is no ImageView. I don't know why it changes, maybe you set the layout_width, layout_height or other parameters wrong in your rows.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just tell a adapter listview.

after that in `holdar.listview` take a event in that event when image is changes put

```
adaptername.notifydatasetchanged();
```